# Different versions of msvcrt in ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes, msvcrt

In Windows, the `ctypes.cdll.msvcrt` object automatically exists when I import the ctypes module, and it represents the `msvcrt` Microsoft C++ runtime library [according to the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries).

However, I notice that there is also a [find_msvcrt](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.util.find_msvcrt) function which will `"return the filename of the VC runtype library used by Python"`.

It further states, `"If you need to free memory, for example, allocated by an extension module with a call to the free(void *), it is important that you use the function in the same library that allocated the memory."`

So my question is, what's the difference between the `ctypes.cdll.msvcrt` library that I already have and the one which I can load with the `find_msvcrt` function?  Under what specific circumstances might they not be the same library?

Comment: related: [what are the differences among the ways to access msvcrt in python on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30790494/4279)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not just that `ctypes.cdll.msvcrt` automatically exists, but `ctypes.cdll.anything` automatically exists, and is loaded on first access, loading `anything.dll`. So `ctypes.cdll.msvcrt` loads `msvcrt.dll`, which is a library that ships as part of Windows. It is not the C runtime that Python links with, so you shouldn't call the malloc/free from `msvcrt`.

For example, for Python 2.6/3.1, you should be using `ctypes.cdll.msvcr90`. As this will change over time, [`find_msvcrt()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.util.find_msvcrt) gives you the name of the library that you should really use (and then load through [`ctypes.CDLL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL)).

Here are the names of a few different versions of the Microsoft CRT, released at various points as part of MSC, VC++, the platform SDK, or Windows: crtdll.dll, msvcrt.dll, msvcrt4.dll, msvcr70.dll, msvcr71.dll, msvcr80.dll, msvcr90.dll.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't spent much time programming in Windows-land, so this kind of detail is extremely helpful.

Comment: so for completeness - ctypes.cdll[ctypes.util.find_msvcrt()] should return a handle to the proper CRT.